# is there a way to restrict the system property java.locale.providers=HOST to just Date and Time

Tags: java, datetime, jvm, locale, formatter

I want to enable my java application to pick date and time formats as per the local system settings for which I am using the below argument:

**java.locale.providers=HOST**

I am new to this argument, I wanted to restrict this to just date and time but I have read that other locale related stuff like currency, number system would also be impacted.

Is there a way to restrict this to just date and time and also is there any better way to achieve this ask?

If any side effects of using this system property in my java application?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to use "the exact" settings they have configured, OR you want to use what's appropriate for a machine configured into *pick the current locale*?

The latter will happen automatically without you needing to set any property - Locale/DateFormatter/etc have getDefault methods that give for the current locale (provided it is one supported by the JDK).

The java.locale.providers=HOST method YMMV ... According to the [LocaleServiceProvider APIDOC](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/spi/LocaleServiceProvider.html) might have issues (you would need to test on all your target platforms) -

> There are two other possible locale sensitive service providers, i.e.,
> "CLDR" which is a provider based on Unicode Consortium's CLDR Project,
> and "HOST" which is a provider that reflects the user's custom
> settings in the underlying operating system. These two providers may
> not be available, depending on the Java Runtime Environment
> implementation.

You may also want to consider what works in your UI - do you have space for a long date (Saturday 25 July, 2002) vs something shorter (25/07/2002 or 2002/07/25).

ALSO what are you worried about changing beyond Date and Time formats - you said "restrict to just Date/Time"??

Comment: Yes I am looking for the exact settings the user has configured, but I have read into documentation that this arguments takes care of date, time, currency and number system as per the locale but I would want to restrict it just to date and time.

Is there a way to achieve this, also what red flags do you see in using this argument.

Comment: You control the formatting - so you don't have to use any xxx.getDefault() instances - you can roll your own, OR choose say the default for en_US locale or the default for en_UK or in_IN.  You have to expect if you take something set by a USER that it might be odd - e.g. a date format like "January, Friday 23, 2020" [i.e. long??] - so if you have a UI plan for it, or handle it (fall back to a sane default).